# What is R"===(?

Tags: c++

Specifically in this file

https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/xmrstak/backend/amd/amd_gpu/opencl/cryptonight.cl

The first line is this and the end ends with

```
)==="
```

And it seems to be sprinkled within.

Could someone explain what this is and does?  I'm having a difficult time googling this.

Comment: [Raw string lieral](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)?

Comment: But how is this used in the code. Why is the whole file a huge literal? Anyone?

Comment: @GillBates Yes, it's a huge literal. The file is included and the string passed to [clCreateProgramWithSource](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/1.0/docs/man/xhtml/clCreateProgramWithSource.html).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The format for the [raw-string literals](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal)[[2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/lex.string#nt:raw-string)] is: `R"delimiter( raw_characters )delimiter"`, so `===` is the delimiter in `R"===(` and [line 243 in your link](https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak/blob/master/xmrstak/backend/amd/amd_gpu/opencl/cryptonight.cl#L243)

Comment: Ah this makes sense, thanks snr.  And user2079303, I haven't dived fully into the code, but thank you for your explanation.